# NestJS - Access user from Guard

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I've been following the official NestJS documentation. I have successfully setup JWT passport authentication. I can access the user details from the @Req within controllers but I'm having issues accessing the user details from within the custom guard.

This works fine

```
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
@Get('me')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
```

This does not (curently logging for debug)

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      console.log('No Roles');
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    
    // Returns Undefined 
    console.log(request.user);
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is how I'm declaring each entry in the controller

```
  @Get()
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  @Roles('admin')
  findAll() {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
```

The pass through of roles metadata is working fine, just looks like the user isn't being appended to the context at the correct step.

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT: updated @UseGuards(RolesGuard), copied and pasted wrong version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like i've fixed it, have to chain them

```
@Get()
  @Roles('admin')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
  findAll() {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are not using the rolesGuard :

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard) // <= replace JwtAuthGuard with your guard: RolesGuard 
@Get('me')
getProfile(@Request() req) {
return req.user;
 }
```

the same for the second method.

Comment: Hey, Getting the same thing, undefined. I did try roles guard before but I copied and pasted the wrong version into here, troubleshooting tunnel vision

Comment: Looks like i've fixed it, need to chain the guards as per my own answer :)